# Как ввести все символы в одну строку в python?

Tags: python, строки, input

Мне по условию задачи нужно ввести все символы в один ряд , вот так: Day, mice. "Year" - a mistake#
Но работает только тогда, когда я ввожу строку посимвольно, можно ли как-то ввести сразу всю строку?

```
maxword = ''
currentword = ''
flag = False
letter = input()
while letter != '#':
    if letter != ' ':
        currentword += letter
        flag = True
    elif flag:
        flag = False
        if len(currentword) > len(maxword) :
            maxword = currentword
        currentword = ''
    letter = input()
if len(currentword) > len(maxword) :
    print(currentword)
else:
    print(maxword)
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте ваш код текстом, вместо скриншота.

Comment: @Andrey, написать задание?

Comment: Нет, просто ваш код добавьте в вопрос вместо картинки. Чтобы другие могли скопировать и запустить у себя.

Comment: @Andrey на вход программы подается последовательность символов, заканчивающихся символом #. Других символов # во входной последовательности нет. Будем называть словом любую последовательность подряд идущих символов, отделенную пробелами. Напишите программу , которая найдет и выведет на экране слово максимальной длины. Если во входной строке несколько слов максимальной длины, необходимо вывести на экран первое такое слово.

Comment: @Andrey, добавил

Comment: @ВаняКарбушев переносы строк допускаются в последовательности?

Comment: @АлексейМ. , мне надо ввести одной строкой

Comment: Во входной строке допускаются переносы?

Comment: @АлексейМ., я не понимаю, мне в задании во входных данных написано 2 строки: на 1) заданная строка и 2) самое длинное первое слово

Comment: @ВаняКарбушев, ладно, это не так важно. Ответил. Условие задачи, которое Вы в комментарии выше оставили, добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @АлексейМ., мне надо сделать как в паскале , там можно написать read вместо readln,а тут как - я не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
max_word = str()

while True:
    words, delimiter = input().partition("#")[:2]
    longest = max(words.split(), key=len)
    if len(longest) > len(max_word):
        max_word = longest
    if delimiter == '#':
        break

print(max_word)
```

Comment: программа не работает

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке покажите.

Comment: и тем более я тут половины не знаю в вашем решении, можно ли как то мое усовершенствовать или в питоне так априори нельзя?

Comment: if len(item) > len(max_word):
NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: Неправильно скопировали код, видимо. Переменная инициализируется в условии цикла строкой выше. Она не может быть not defined.

Comment: ладно, видимо ,я и правда что то не так скопировал, но во 1) выводит mistake# , вместо mistake и это реально сложновато еще для меня

Comment: Про отсечение символа '#' в условии не сказано. Прочитайте про циклы, списки и методы строк в питоне. Иначе сложно будет разобраться.

Comment: а более простым способом никак, да?

Comment: Этот способ - проще некуда. Вам нужно выяснить, что возвращает функция input(), функции split() и len() и т.д. по коду. Там всего несколько строк. Тогда разберётесь.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо вам

Comment: Добавил отсечение # и комментарии в код, чтобы проще было разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем эта куча циклов: дожидаетесь ввода => берете все что до знака # => разделяете на слова по пробелу => ищете максимальное (`max`) слово по ключу `len` (и по новой если надо - поэтому `while True`)

```py
while True:
    input_data = input().partition("#")[0].split()
    print(max(input_data, key=len))
```

Comment: "последовательность символов, заканчивающихся символом #" - последовательность можно передать в несколько строк. А вывести нужно одно слово.

Comment: Но вложенного цикла можно не делать. Это правда. Спасибо, поправил ответ.